# BeautifulSoup Nested class selector

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup for a project. Here is my HTML structure

```
<div class="container">
<div class="fruits">
    <div class="apple">
        <p>John</p>
        <p>Sam</p>
        <p>Bailey</p>
        <p>Jack</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Sour</li>
            <li>Sweet</li>
            <li>Salty</li>
        </ul>
        <span>Fruits are good</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mango">
        <p>Randy</p>
        <p>James</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="apple">
    <p>Bill</p>
    <p>Sean</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to grab text in div class *'apple'* which falls under class *'fruits'*

This is what I have tried so far ....

```
for node in soup.find_all("div", class_="apple")
```

Its returning ...

- Bill
- Sean

But I want it to return only ...

- John
- Sam
- Bailey
- Jack
- Sour
- Sweet
- Salty
- Fruits are good

**Please note that I DO NOT know the exact structure of elements inside *div class="apple"* There can be any type of different HTML elements inside that class. So the selector has to be flexible enough.**

Here is the full code, where I need to add this BeautifulSoup code ...

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'dknnews'
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/uat-area/scrapy/all-news-listing/_recache']
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'lxml')
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(content.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
        nf = NewsFields()
        ptype = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dknpagetype"})
        ptitle = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dknpagetitle"})
        pturl = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dknpageurl"})
        ptdate = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dknpagedate"})
        ptdesc = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dknpagedescription"})
        for node in soup.find_all("div", class_="apple"): <!-- THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD THE BS CODE -->
         ptbody = ''.join(node.find_all(text=True))
         ptbody = ' '.join(ptbody.split())
         nf['pagetype'] = ptype[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
         nf['pagetitle'] = ptitle[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
         nf['pageurl'] = pturl[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
         nf['pagedate'] = ptdate[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
         nf['pagedescription'] = ptdesc[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
         nf['bodytext'] = ptbody.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
         yield nf
        for url in hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="scrapy"]/li/a/@href').extract():
         yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

I am not sure how to use nested selectors with BeautifulSoup find_all ?

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

```
soup.select('.fruits .apple p')
```

use [CSSselector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), it's very easy to express class.

```
soup.find(class_='fruits').find(class_="apple").find_all('p')
```

Or, you can use `find()` to get the `p` tag step by step

EDIT:

```
[s  for div in soup.select('.fruits .apple') for s in div.stripped_strings]
```

use `strings` generator to get all the string under the `div` tag, `stripped_strings` will get rid of `\n` in the results.

out:

```
['John', 'Sam', 'Bailey', 'Jack', 'Sour', 'Sweet', 'Salty', 'Fruits are good']
```

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source_code = """<div class="container">
<div class="fruits">
    <div class="apple">
        <p>John</p>
        <p>Sam</p>
        <p>Bailey</p>
        <p>Jack</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Sour</li>
            <li>Sweet</li>
            <li>Salty</li>
        </ul>
        <span>Fruits are good</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mango">
        <p>Randy</p>
        <p>James</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="apple">
    <p>Bill</p>
    <p>Sean</p>
</div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'lxml')
[s  for div in soup.select('.fruits .apple') for s in div.stripped_strings]
```

Comment: Thanks but there are 2 divs in the code with class 'apple'. Do you think your code will target only the div that falls under class 'fruits' ?

Comment: @Puneet Sharma you changed your output in the question, and I update it.

Comment: I am getting "invalid  syntax" error when I used your code. I have tried your code with and without array.

Comment: Please see the updated code. I have added your code in the code I pasted above, and I got "invalid syntax" error ....

Comment: Getting this error on next line ...     `ptbody = ''.join(s.find_all(text=True))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
`